# Is there a rational response to the idea that my death is the ultimate evil?

Tags: death

Is there a rational response to the idea that my death is the ultimate evil? I'm asking just because I can't think of useful response, assuming my death is necessary -- inescapable, and most philosophers would I think agree that all men are mortal. Perhaps just a lack of imagination, but I'd like to know if anyone answers this question.

By "ultimate evil" I mean something that cannot be mitigated, made less evil, through life or religion or some combination of them. However, I don't think my death is irredeemable, the "ultimate evil", so I'd be interested in any philosopher who claims it is.

I'm interested in an answer from any robust moral standpoint except relativism, but especially atheist ones, whether or not I'm agnostic.

Comment: Being "unavoidable" does not automatically absolve something of being bad. Our mortality is only an empirical generalization, so its unavoidability is open to future revision. It is not, on its face, irrational, to pursue longevity or even immortality, and if that can be an ideal then death can be something "evil", i.e. undesirable. I do not know about the "ultimate", there are things worse than death, some say. But one can easily imagine a kind of humanistic ethics, with a good measure of egocentrism, that would support such a claim.

Comment: Please define "evil". Evil suggests some kind of absolute right and wrong not depending on the subject. Its being featured in the question is at odd with the idea that "your" feat would have anymore significance than any other. It also suggests some kind of moral framework, which you don't specify. The answer heavily depends on which moral framework is considered.

Comment: yeah i totally agree with that comment's resolution, thanks @Conifold -- even as i went in the opposite direction to your claim.

Comment: that's a useful request for / clarification, thanks @armand , however, i have an answer to my question now, more or less, so i'm not sure if i need to edit the question. perhaps?

Comment: fwiw i think immortality -- literal not spiritual -- could be an irrational desire, because an infinite project is impossible, and an infinite number of projects would be trivial. ymmv of course @Conifold

Comment: without things ending they seem meaningless to me. even pleasures

Comment: Why does there need to be a "project"? Why can it not be infinitely long if there is one? And why can't one have an infinite chain of non-trivial projects building upon each other, or independent? Ancients had a prohibition on infinite regress, but they never had a good argument for it, it was a postulate. Immortality is often depicted as a bane in literature (e.g. by Swift in Laputa), but then there are others that show it as desirable, e.g. Man from Earth movie. Neither side has a plausible argument either, it is all imaginative guessing on tea leaves that they have no experiential basis for

Comment: @Conifold just 'meaning' that's all

Comment: i don't understand your comment @Conifold you seem to leap from it involving the imagination to having no -- philosophical -- answer. it may have no conclusive answer, but what does i mean

Comment: If it has no conclusive answer, and specifically, if there is no plausible rational argument against an answer, then proposing such an answer is not irrational.

Comment: Your question seem to presuppose that your death is the ultimate evil. If we generalize this to the third person's 'one's death' in the sense that humans tend towards seeing the ending of their life as a bad, a rational response need simply demonstrate that some human values outweigh living. Sacrificing oneself for one's children is the obvious ethical example. ALL ethics is a rational argument endorsing the supremacy of one value over another. The continuation of one's life, like all values, is generally weighed against other values and virtues.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't remember whether this addressed the moral component, the book [Dream, Death, and the Self](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691128597/dream-death-and-the-self) by JJ Valberg considers at length the other component of the question, that it seems there is nothing after *my* death, and yet also of course we expect the world to go on after that.  From the overview:

> This ceasing to be presents itself solipsistically not just as the end of everything “for me” but as the end of everything absolutely. Yet since it is the same for everyone, this cannot be. Death thus confronts us with an impossible fact: something that cannot be but will be.

Answer (score 0):

Death is the reason why we are who we are. All creatures evolve through natural selection which involves the survival of the fittest; i.e. those best suited to proliferate in an environment continue to pass their traits such that the lineage lives on while the rest are eliminated. If it were not for death organisms--both well suited and poorly suited-- would continue to flourish. With each generation there would be more and more genetic divergence and as a consequence we would become increasingly dissimilar. Thus death not only made us strong to survive the forces of nature, but also is responsible for a giving us a sense of community and unity based on preserving the gene pool.

Therefore, since death has given us some good things it cannot be the ultimate evil.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Gray_(philosopher)

> only creatures that live in passing time can know moments of undying
> value.
>
> There are no such moments in a life that can never end. In such a
> life, there's nothing to treasure, nothing that has value because it
> cannot come again.... The paradox is that it's only because we die
> that we can know what it truly means to be immortal.

the [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-19004818)